# Only solution to Diophantine equation with primes?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

Find all solutions to:

$$p_1 ^2 - p_2^2 = p_3^2 + 1$$

where $p_i$ is a prime number (positive of-course)
The only solution that seems to exist is $(3,2,2)$ for $(p_1, p_2, p_3)$ accordingly. But I have no clue how to prove that no other solutions exist..
The only thing that jumps to my mind is assuming that another solution exists and somehow get to a contradiction...

I would highly appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: Hint: $p^2\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ if $p$ is odd.

Comment: $3 \mid p^2 -1$ for $p \ne 3$. Then check $p_1^2 -1 - p_2^2+1=p_3^2-1+2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(p_1,p_2,p_3)\ne(3,2,2)$ If $p_1=2$ then we have $p_2^2+p_3^2=3$ which is impossible by the known theorem on the representation of a natural integer as a sum of two squares. Thus $p_1$ must be odd but in this case we have $p_2^2+p_3^2\equiv0\pmod4$ which is impossible since $p_2$ or $p_3$ must be distinct of $2$.

Answer (score 1):

The square of a prime can only be $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$; the difference of two such squares cannot be $2$ modulo $4$. However, the RHS is $2$ modulo $4$ if $p_3$ is an odd prime. Thus $p_3=2$; this implies (again by the modular argument) that $p_2=2$, hence $p_1=3$ and the only solution is $3^2-2^2=2^2+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Taken mod $8$, the squares of primes leave remainders $4$ (for $p=2$) and $1$ (for all odd primes). The only combination of those two remainders that satisfy the congruence $a-b\equiv c+1$ mod $8$ is $1-4\equiv4+1$ mod $8$, which means we need $p_2=p_3=2$, which in turns implies $p_1=3$.

Answer (score 0):

**Continuation of my comment** and an alternative solution, from [FLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)
$$3 \mid p^2 -1$$ for $p \ne 3$.
Then check
$$ p_1^2 - p_2^2=p_3^2+1 \tag{1}$$
$$\iff p_1^2 -1 - p_2^2+1=p_3^2-1+2$$
This will lead to $3 \mid 2$, if none of $p_1,p_2$ and $p_3$ is $3$. Thus, at least one of $p_1,p_2$ or $p_3$ must be $3$.

- if $p_1=3$ then $9-p_2^2=p_3^2+1$ yields $p_2=2$, since any other value will make $9-p_2^2\leq 0$, whether the RHS of $(1)$ is always positive.
- for this case, either $p_2=3$ or $p_3=3$ doesn't matter, we can swap them. So we have $$(p_1-p_2)(p_1+p_2)=p_1^2-p_2^2=10=2\cdot5$$ just 2 case to analyse $p_1-p_2=1,p_1+p_2=10$ and $p_1-p_2=2,p_1+p_2=5$.